# Swift Package Module name conflicting with struct, class or any type defined in other Modules

Tags: swift, package, swift-package-manager

created Swift Package Module with name `OSLogBoolFormat` and then I have to `import os` in the code. when I try to access types defined in `OSLogBoolFormat` module it's not being recognized and its only pointing to `os.OSLogBoolFormat`.

```
import UIKit;
import os;
import OSLogBoolFormat;

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let name = OSLogBoolFormat.PrcoessKT.name
        print(name)

    }
}
```

OSLogBoolFormat package is conflicting with OSLogBoolFormat enum defined in os Module.

> Code Example: https://github.com/sreexamus/NewOneTest